# cpp std::copy problems during compilation : no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<unsigned_char>

Tags: c++

*** solved ***

i've got a problem when compiling a class that I've written, when implementing a copy-constructor. the class holds as a field a struct which holds all relevant data, which I send to a function called clone, which copies the relevant fields of the struct to the newly constructed class.

```
struct tMicroControllerVersion
{
    unsigned char  PMC_Version [2]; // major,minor
    unsigned char  FPGA_Version [2];
    unsigned char  project_ID   [2];
    unsigned char  configuration_Type;
    unsigned char  PCB_Revision;
    unsigned char  Unit_Serial_No [6];
    unsigned char  Unit_Part_No [8];
    unsigned char  FPGA_device_ID;
    unsigned char  PMC_device_ID;
    unsigned char  Reserved [29];

    tMicroControllerVersion()
    {
      memset(this, 0, sizeof(tMicroControllerVersion));
    }
};
```

my clone method looks like this:

```
    void CMicroControllerVersionMsg::clone(tMicroControllerVersion other)
    {
      std::copy(std::begin(other.PMC_Version),std::end(PMC_Version),this -> _data.body.PMC_Version);
      std::copy(std::begin(other.FPGA_Version),std::end(other.FPGA_Version),this -> _data.body. FPGA_Version);
      std::copy(std::begin(other.project_ID),std::end(other.project_ID),this -> _data.body. project_ID);
      this._data.body.configuration_type = other.configuration_type
      ...
    }
```

edit: this is how the class looks

```
#include <cstring>

#include "Tac4gInfras/Communication/SrcImp/BaseMessage.h"

#include "Tac4gPackages/FpgaTsComm/SrcImp/Messages/MCTsHeader.h"


#pragma pack(push, 1)
namespace FpgaTsCommNS
{

struct tMicroControllerVersion
{
    unsigned char  PMC_Version [2]; // major,minor
    unsigned char  FPGA_Version [2];
    unsigned char  project_ID   [2];
    unsigned char  configuration_Type;
    unsigned char  PCB_Revision;
    unsigned char  Unit_Serial_No [6];
    unsigned char  Unit_Part_No [8];
    unsigned char  FPGA_device_ID;
    unsigned char  PMC_device_ID;
    unsigned char  Reserved [29];

    tMicroControllerVersion()
    {
      memset(this, 0, sizeof(tMicroControllerVersion));
    }

};

struct tMicroControllerVersionResp
{
    /// Message data.
    tMicroControllerVersion body;
};

class CMicroControllerVersionMsg: public BaseMessage
{
public:

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///  \brief  Constructor
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    CMicroControllerVersionMsg();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///  \brief  Constructor
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    CMicroControllerVersionMsg(CMicroControllerVersionMsg* pToCopy);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///  \brief Destructor.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    virtual ~CMicroControllerVersionMsg();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///  \brief  ToString for message
    ///
    ///  \param direction - direction for message
    ///  \return  message buffer in string format
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    virtual string ToString();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///  \brief Validate message content.
    ///
    ///  \return True if message is valid, false otherwise.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    virtual bool Validate();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///  \brief  data clone
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void clone(tMicroControllerVersion other);

protected:

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///  \brief Get class size.
    ///
    ///  \return Derived class size.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    virtual unsigned int GetClassSize();

public:
    /// data of the message
    tMicroControllerVersionResp _data;

};

}//namespace FpgaTsCommNS
#pragma pack(pop)

#endif  // _MICRO_CONTROLLER_VERSION_RESP_MSG_H
```

when compiling i get an error

"no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<unsigned_char>'"
the weird thing is that in other versions of my code, this use of copy with similar structs has passed compilation, so I'm rather at a loss here of what to do. ofc i can manually insert each value of the unsigned char arrays, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

note: when I say that something passed compilation I mean that I compile it using a makefile, and not some IDE compiler.

edit 2:
solved the problem, using std::copy should be like this:

```
std::copy(std::begin(other.FPGA_Version),std::end(other.FPGA_Version),std::begin(this -> _data.body.FPGA_Version));
```

Comment: Are you missing `other` in `std::end(PMC_Version)`... first line of `clone` method?

Comment: What is `CMicroControllerVersionMsg`? Show a [mcve]

Comment: Also `this._data.body.configuration_type = other.configuration_type` should be `this->_data.body.configuration_type = other.configuration_type`?

Comment: edited my original comment to show how the class looks like

Answer (score 0):

After a little refactoring it compiles fine on http://cpp.sh/ except the line:

```
this._data.body.configuration_type = other.configuration_type
```

this is a pointer so use '->'

```
struct tMicroControllerVersion
{
    unsigned char  PMC_Version [2]; // major,minor
    unsigned char  FPGA_Version [2];
    unsigned char  project_ID   [2];
    unsigned char  configuration_Type;
    unsigned char  PCB_Revision;
    unsigned char  Unit_Serial_No [6];
    unsigned char  Unit_Part_No [8];
    unsigned char  FPGA_device_ID;
    unsigned char  PMC_device_ID;
    unsigned char  Reserved [29];

    tMicroControllerVersion()
    {
      memset(this, 0, sizeof(tMicroControllerVersion));
    }
    
    void clone(tMicroControllerVersion other);
};

void tMicroControllerVersion::clone(tMicroControllerVersion other)
    {
      std::copy(std::begin(other.PMC_Version),std::end(PMC_Version),this->PMC_Version);
      std::copy(std::begin(other.FPGA_Version),std::end(other.FPGA_Version),this->FPGA_Version);
      std::copy(std::begin(other.project_ID),std::end(other.project_ID),this->project_ID);
      this->configuration_Type = other.configuration_Type;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the response, ive added how the class looks (named body in the class),
the struct I'm looking to copy the contents of is wrapped inside another struct (called _data in the class), so that's why I wrote my code the way I wrote it